# How to use ManagedIdentity in Azure Function storage account connection string

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, connection-string, azure-managed-identity, azure-durable-functions

I have an `Azure Function` that is using `durable functions`:

local.settings.json

```json
"Values": {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "DurableFunctionsStorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
```

host.json

```json
"extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "storageProvider": {
                "connectionStringName": "DurableFunctionsStorageConnectionString"
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of using connection string with an access key in Azure environment, I would like to use a managed identity and give it access. Is there a version of the connection string that is supported that can use managed identity?

This is an example of a similar access for SignalR connection string:

```
Endpoint={signalr_service_endpoint};AuthType=aad;Version=1.0;
```

It's even better if there is a possibility for `DefaultAzureCredential` from `Azure.Identity`, but it will suffice for me to "turn on" Managed Identity.

P.S. I am not looking on how to connect to a storage account in my code, but how to make Azure Function infrastructure to do it for the accounts that it needs.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-storage-managed-identity/using-managed-identity-between-azure-functions-and-azure-storage/?

Comment: Yes, in fact right before writing the question :) What is discussed there is how to connect to a storage inside function code. They do use ordinary connection string there themselves for the storage that the Function infrastructure connects to. And they do use `DefaultAzureCredential` there. It took me a while to figure it out myself. I'll alter question to make it more clear

Comment: it doesnt look like it s supported for durable function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#configure-an-identity-based-connection.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it actually describes how to achieve it for ordinary storage. There is so much docs everywhere, hard to find the right one sometimes :)

Comment: Yeah it s still in preview and not supported for durable function. You can follow this open issue for durabe function https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1793

Comment: I have posted an answer based on your comments @Thomas, you can post your own and I'll accept it if you want :) Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to useful comments by @Thomas, I figured out that:

1. It is possible to do for ordinary storage account by providing this variable:

   `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName`: the value is just the name of storage account. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#connecting-to-host-storage-with-an-identity).
2. It is not possible for Durable functions yet. See this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1793).

Comment: You can [now](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases/tag/v2.7.0) use durable functions with managed identities

Answer (score 0):

I come from the Azure SignalR Service team.

It is not recommended to use `ConnectionString` while configuring AAD Auth.

Even us is updating our docs to recommend our customers to configure AAD Auth in codes.

I'm not sure what feature of Azure storage that you're using. For `Blobs`, you could configure a `BlobClient` through the following codes:

```cs
var client = new BlobClient(new Uri("<your endpoint>"), new DefaultAzureCredential(), new BlobClientOptions());
```

[BlobClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet)

To learn more about other derived `TokenCredential` class, see [TokenCredential class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using any blob storage feature directly, I am using it as a part of Azure Function. Could you please provide more details on not recommending the connection string, I did not quite get it? I use the one I have posted with managed identity and it seems to work fine